# actor lifeline in a sequence diagram of papyrus

Tags: sequence-diagram, papyrus

I would like to know if it is possible to have the draw of an "actor" lifeline in a sequence diagram of Papyrus.

I created an actor in the model and when I drag and drop the actor in the sequence diagram I get a common rectangle icon instead of the actor icon for the lifeline.